# Sony SmartWatch Game Loop example

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

Has anyone got a decent example of a game loop for the Sony SmartWatch? The 8 game sample is quite confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look on the Control API example in the [SDK](http://developer.sonymobile.com/cws/devworld/technology/smart-extras/smart-extension-sdk) first (which is without any game logic), and try to add your own game logic to that, because I can't really imagine any easier game than the 8 game or tic-tac-toe on a small screen like that.